# tradingview Mobile terminal device adaptation

Tags: tradingview-api

Tradingview mobile terminal adaptation problem. Whether you need to use `CSS` or the `Tradingview official configuration`

Tradingview needs to adapt to the mobile terminal device, but it is not feasible to set left_toolbar in enabled_features, but sidebar appears in the official demo of Tradingview

Other pop-ups are not very adaptive how can they be consistent with the Tradingview

```
enabled_features: [
                'study_templates',
                'left_toolbar', // side-bar
                "show_left_toolbar_by_default"
            ],
```

// There is no effect

// How can I adapt to mobile terminal like tradingview website

// Problematic images in the comments section

Comment: https://image-static.segmentfault.com/565/891/565891420-5d5d00ce42bb1_articlex

Comment: left_toolbar :  https://image-static.segmentfault.com/399/551/3995516460-5d5d00365ef55_articlex